# Problem plotting 3D graph of integral of f(x,y,t) dt

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder, integral

I have defined a function I(a,b) = integral f(a,b,t) dt and want to plot it to see how it depend on the variables a and b. I first wrote a program that graphed  y = I(k,x) and it worked just fine, but i wanted to see how it depends on both variables so i tried to write a program that graphs it in 3D.

The program worked for simpler functions like trigonometric and polynomials, but when i try to graph I(x,y) it just gives me the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

This is the code, I originally wrote my own program to approximate the integral but then used scipy

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def integral(x,y):
    return integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((x**2 + y**2 - 2*x*y*np.cos(np.pi*t*(np.sqrt(1/x**3) - np.sqrt(1/y**3))))/(x**3*y**3)), 0,  np.sqrt(x**3*y**3))

X = np.arange(0.1,5,0.1)
Y = np.arange(0.1,5,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = integral(X,Y)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='green')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')


ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='winter', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('copper');

plt.show()
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.integrate.quad` returns a tuple. You only want the first value of that. Also you need to vectorize the function.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def integral(x,y):
    return integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((x**2 + y**2 - 2*x*y*np.cos(np.pi*t*(np.sqrt(1/x**3) - np.sqrt(1/y**3))))/(x**3*y**3)), 0,  np.sqrt(x**3*y**3))[0]

X = np.arange(0.1,5,0.1)
Y = np.arange(0.1,5,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.vectorize(integral)(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='green')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')


ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='winter', norm=plt.Normalize(np.nanmin(Z), np.nanmax(Z)), edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem with my original code (that didnt use scipy) was that I didn't vectorize it? Why do i need to vectorize this function but not other functions like for example np.sin(x,y)?

Comment: Numpy functions are already vectorized, i.e. you can compute `np.sin([1,2,3,4])`.